# How to add an object to ActiveObject?

Tags: fabricjs

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1YgD.png)

I want to add a small rectangle (acting as a button for external file) to any object and create a group which would move together on the canvas. User would have ability to remove the button later if not needed.

Can anyone please suggest a good way to achieve this?

I have managed to add a custom context menu and add a button to the image but I'm not able to group the active object and the button togehter.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/fbgu7697/2/

```
function newRect(index) {
    return new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top: index * 30,
    left: index * 30,
    fill: '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6),
  });
}

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var rect0 = newRect(0);
canvas.add(rect0);

var rect1 = newRect(1);
canvas.add(rect1);

var rect2 = newRect(2);
canvas.add(rect2);

var group = new fabric.Group([rect0, rect1]);

canvas.setActiveGroup(group).renderAll();

setTimeout(function() {
  canvas.discardActiveGroup().renderAll();
}, 5000);
```